# HDP's HDFS replication process really slow

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication, hortonworks-data-platform

I am currently working with both `CDH` and `HDP`. My `CDH` system's replication process works very well but `HDP` doesn't

For example:

- When I set the replication factor for large directory in `HDFS` (20TB) to 2, HDFS need to delete `2 millions blocks`
- When I set again the replication factor for above directory to 3, HDFS will need to resolve about `2 millions under replicated blocks`

In `CDH`, I only took ***3-5 hours or less*** to complete but `HDP` took me about ***2 days***.

I want to improve the speed for replication process in `HDP`.

I have searched around and found that changing some replication configs for `HDFS` maybe help. I also found that `HDP` miss these configs compare to `CDH`:

- dfs.namenode.replication.max-streams (default: 2, CDH: 20)
- dfs.namenode.replication.max-streams-hard-limit (default: 4, CDH: 40)
- dfs.namenode.replication.work.multiplier.per.iteration (default: 2, CDH: 30)

I changed above configs in `HDP` similar to `CDH` but no luck. Hope someone can help!

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Abhinav I want to know how to improve the speed for replication process in HDP